# How can I align the trailing alignment of the view to its parent's vertical axis?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm trying to make the following layout using `SwiftUI`.
[image: screenshot]

The `trailing` `alignment` of the form labels is aligned to the center of the parent's view. Similarly, the leading alignment of the `TextFields` is also aligned to the center of the parent's view.

I have the following code -

```swift
        HStack {
            Spacer()
            VStack {
                HStack {
                    Spacer()
                    Text("Name")
                    TextField("", text: .constant(""))
                        .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
                        .frame(maxWidth: 100)
                }

                HStack {
                    Spacer()
                    Text("Adress")
                    TextField("", text: .constant(""))
                        .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
                        .frame(maxWidth: 100)
                }

                HStack {
                    Spacer()
                    Text("Short Description")
                    TextField("", text: .constant(""))
                        .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
                        .frame(maxWidth: 100)
                }
            }
            .layoutPriority(1)
            Spacer()
        }
```

which results in

[image: iphone]

Comment: I tried your code out and two things. (1) You didn't post the `struct` for `BorderedTextField` so I made do with `TextField` and a value of 10 underscores. (2) But the real question is why are you adding a modifier of `layoutPriority(1)`? Commenting it out fixes your issue.

Comment: @dfd I've updated the code as well as the screenshots to make it clearer. Removing the `layoutPriority(1)` results in https://i.imgur.com/IS06CMN.png because the form does not have priority over the Spacers to fit.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have `Xcode` at the moment but why can't you put all the texts into a `Vstack`and the `TextField` into a separate `Vstack`? Something like this

```
   HStack {
        HStack {        
            VStack(alignment: .trailing) {
                Spacer()
                Text("Name")
                Text("Adress")
                Text("Short Description")

            }

            VStack{

                BorderedTextField(placeholder: "", text: .constant(""))
                    .frame(maxWidth: 100)
                BorderedTextField(placeholder: "", text: .constant(""))
                    .frame(maxWidth: 100)
                BorderedTextField(placeholder: "", text: .constant(""))
                .frame(maxWidth: 100)
            }
        }
        .layoutPriority(1)
        Spacer()
    }
```

Another possibility is creating a custom alignment, there's a really good talk about this [here from WWDC](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/237/)

Comment: Custom alignment is a possibility but I'm hoping there's a solution using the default alignments given that it is possible to do this without SwiftUI. We essentially want to align the trailing alignment of the form labels to the center guide of the parent's view.

Comment: I thought about two VStack also, but I'd expect the horizontal alignment of each cell may be off due to the fonts being used.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a possible solution that works using `GeometryReader`. I'm still hoping there's a better way to do this but this works:

```swift
      GeometryReader { proxy in
            HStack {
                VStack(spacing: 20) {
                    HStack {
                        Spacer()
                        Text("Name")
                    }

                    HStack {
                        Spacer()
                        Text("Address")
                    }

                    HStack {
                        Spacer()
                        Text("Short Description")
                    }
                }.frame(width: proxy.size.width / 2)

                VStack {
                    HStack {
                        TextField("", text: .constant(""))
                            .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
                            .frame(maxWidth: 120)
                        Spacer()
                    }

                    HStack {
                        TextField("", text: .constant(""))
                            .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
                            .frame(maxWidth: 120)
                        Spacer()
                    }

                    HStack {
                        TextField("", text: .constant(""))
                            .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
                            .frame(maxWidth: 120)
                        Spacer()
                    }
                }.frame(width: proxy.size.width / 2)
            }
        }
```

- Divides the screen into 2 equal columns using the parent's width
- Places all the form labels in the first column and the fields in the 2nd column
- Adjust the spacing between the form labels to make them align with their corresponding fields

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think I've managed to do what you asked for. Your solutions are a clear so-called over-engineering. Try using less views, and try out different configurations before going so deep using `GeometryReader`s. Here's my code (I wrapped fields in `ForEach`):

Fields:

```swift
private var fields: some View {
    VStack(alignment: .trailing) {
        ForEach(["Name", "Adress", "Short Description"], id: \.self) { s in
            HStack {
                Text(s)
                TextField("", text: .constant(""))
                    .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
                    .frame(maxWidth: 100)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

View:

```swift
var body: some View {
    ZStack {
        Spacer()
        fields
            .alignmentGuide(HorizontalAlignment.center) { d in d.width - 100 }
    }
}
```

This is working assuming that width of the text fields's remain fixed. For more complex interfaces don't avoid using custom alignments, they're pretty cool. I advice watching WWDC sessions about that, especially [this one](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/237/)

Hope that helps